# Creat .BAT to copy a .mdb from network drive to local C:/

Tags: networking, batch-file, file-copying

I hope I can get some help with this from someone here on this awesome website.
Im a complete noob when it comes to writing batch scripts and I would really like some help.

My situation..
I currently have a network drive on a PC running Windows Server 2008. The drive letter is I:/
within the I-drive, I have a folder named aaaaeast and within that folder is all of my .mdb's
I would like the .bat to copy a specific .mdb from I:/aaaaeast/ to a XP SP3 machine I have in the other room on startup.

Ive tried
copy \myserver\myshare\myfolder\myfile.txt c:\myfiles

But it fails to find the network path.

I know this is got to be a permission issue. My network doesnt have a domain and all the PC's I map to the I:/ map through the Guest account on the Win 2008 server using (username: Guest with no password)

Can someone please help or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Can you use [Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy)?  It's free and may already be installed.

Comment: Are you trying to have this file copied to the XP machine when it starts up or when the server starts up?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this works for me where I work. There is a mapped drive to the location where the master .mdb is.

That is "i:\" drive.

copy i:\ets\lead\software\paint\leadmain.mdb c:\paint

it copies the .mdb to the "c:\paint" drive on the computer where the client clicked on the .bat file. It has been a while so I can't remember where the .bat file sits. Pretty sure it is on the client's computer.

Open Notepad, add the code above, and save making sure to pick the option "All files" down below. That way you can change the extension to .bat from .txt.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but that doesnt seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 copy \\myserver\myshare\myfolder\myfile.txt c:\myfiles
```

Note: double-backslash

A UNC path (path to a network resource) requires that the target computer name be preceded by two backslashes. Otherwise, starting with \ means "start at the root of the current drive". (Perhaps this was just a typo in the post—that wouldn't cause an error 53.)

Regarding accounts, Windows doesn't really like no-password accounts. There are times when it won't let authentication succeed for a null password. You might try creating an account (with the same name as the username/password on the XP machine) on the 2008 machine and trying it just to see if the user has access to the share. A simple test of that would be something like "dir \myserver\myshare".

If you didn't want to sync accounts, you could create a third user on the 2008 machine and map the share (from the XP machine) as that user. You can also tell Windows to remember the credentials it used for that mapping if you wanted to (i.e. for convenience, definitely **not** security).